# A question on proving the existence of a martingle which has a deterministic square bracket

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $g:\mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ be a non decreasing and continuous function . Show that there exists a continuous martingale  M such that its square bracket $<M>_t=g(t)-g(0)?)$

I have spent a few hours thinking about this question is a practice problem from my course on Stochastic calculus. I tried to consider the "martingale" $M_t=B_{g(t)}$ where B is a $1$-dim B.M which unfortunately did not work $M_t$ was not adapted.

The only continuous martingale which I can think of and play around with is a B.M.
Any ideas as to how should I approach this problem?
Even a hint would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Fix some square-integrable function $h$ and compute the square bracket of the process $X$ defined by $$X_t=\int_0^th(s)\mathrm dB_s.$$

Comment: Thank you. I now recall the theorem we did in the class which says that if we pick a square integrable function then $\exists$ a modification of $ M_t of X_t$ s.th $M_t \in \mathbb{H_C^2}$ I need to master these theorems well.I really appreciate the help.